# npm install -g yo tunneling socket error

Tags: node.js

I am not able to run the command npm install -g yo .. and I am getting the following error !

E:\OneWeb\ngApp1>npm install -g yo
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! node v6.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.3
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET

npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=write EPROTO 101057795:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:794:
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\OneWeb\ngApp1\npm-debug.log

Comment: Run this command first "npm config set https_proxy" and then try the above command.

Answer (score 4):

Experienced a similar issue.

Was able to resolve by removing proxy variables from the .npmrc and then ensuring proxy environment variables were set properly (some were https instead of http).

```
registry=http://registry.npmjs.org/
proxy=http://xxxx:xxxx/
```

Answer (score 2):

Just replace https with http while exporting the proxy:

```
export HTTPS_PROXY="http://myproxy.com:8080"
```

## instead of

```
export HTTPS_PROXY="https://myproxy.com:8080"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try setting the registry server:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm cache clean
```

Does that help at all? If not, try changing it to the HTTPS registry (https://registry.npmjs.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Also set strict-ssl to false with the command:
`npm config set strict-ssl false`